# MariaDB Issue Starting

Tags: mariadb, linux

I have MariaDB installed but I am unable to get it to run, this is what I am getting when I try to run it:

```shell
[andy@andy-laptop ~]$ sudo systemctl status mysqld
× mariadb.service - MariaDB 11.3.2 database server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-03-24 12:33:53 CDT; 18min ago
       Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
             https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
    Process: 3278 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 3280 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]   && systemctl set-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION=$VAR || exit 1 (code=ex>
    Process: 3307 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 3307 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"
        CPU: 286ms

Mar 24 12:33:53 andy-laptop mariadbd[3307]: 2024-03-24 12:33:53 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist". Some plugins may be not loaded
Mar 24 12:33:53 andy-laptop mariadbd[3307]: 2024-03-24 12:33:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 240324 12:33:53
Mar 24 12:33:53 andy-laptop mariadbd[3307]: 2024-03-24 12:33:53 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
Mar 24 12:33:53 andy-laptop mariadbd[3307]: 2024-03-24 12:33:53 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
Mar 24 12:33:53 andy-laptop mariadbd[3307]: 2024-03-24 12:33:53 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
Mar 24 12:33:53 andy-laptop mariadbd[3307]: 2024-03-24 12:33:53 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.db' doesn't exist
Mar 24 12:33:53 andy-laptop mariadbd[3307]: 2024-03-24 12:33:53 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Mar 24 12:33:53 andy-laptop systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 24 12:33:53 andy-laptop systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 24 12:33:53 andy-laptop systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 11.3.2 database server.
```

I have reinstalled Mariadb and I still get the same issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL fails to start on arch Linux. Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171396/mysql-fails-to-start-on-arch-linux-fatal-error-cant-open-and-lock-privilege-t)

Comment: recommend including `journalctl -n 50 -u mariadb.service` output into your question before solutions can be guessed with so little information.